# Unable to create Topic in Netbase Insight API

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am working on Netbase Insight API.We want to create an appliction which gives us a sentiment analysis of a particlular brand in social networking site. We Zerored in on Netbase. We are facing certain issues. We want to understand how do we create a new topic. As in when we try to search for a word using Insight API, it is asking us to fill a field topic.which has a description "Specifies the ID of a topic defined in a NetBase application. You can only specify one topic per call. To view a list of topics the logged-in user can access, use the topics method. This method requires either a topicIds or topics specification. ". We are unable to create a new topic

Answer (score 0):

sorry for your trouble but I'm with NetBase and can explain what's going on.  Our API does not allow the creation of a topic.  The topic has to be created through the user interface.  From there the API can be called to retrieve the net sentiment, passion intensity, and other metrics about that brand.

We like to go over this with developers who use our API, but unfortunately it looks like you didn't get that proper introduction.